# how to access to variable from StatefulWidget to State class flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to pass data from page one to page two data is pass OK but I have one problem now.
this is my code:

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int itemHolder ;
  SecondScreen({Key key, @required this.itemHolder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new mainState();

  }
}

class mainState extends State <SecondScreen> {
  bool value = false ;
  MyPreferences _myPreferences = MyPreferences();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    initial();

  }

  void initial() async {
    setState(() {

    });
  }
  final String apiURL = 'http://xxxxxxxxx/getFlowersList.php';
  Future<List<Flowerdata>> fetchFlowers() async {
    var response = await http.get(apiURL);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      List<Flowerdata> listOfFruits = items.map<Flowerdata>((json) {
        return Flowerdata.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();

      return listOfFruits;
    }
    else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data from Server.');
    }
  }
```

I try to use var (itemHolder ) in the link like that:

```
  final String apiURL = 'http://xxxxxxx/getFlowersList.php?id=' +itemHolder;
```

but I get error:

```
Undefined name 'itemHolder'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
```

I can access to itemHolder. So how can I access to it?

Comment: Use this instead: `final String apiURL = 'http://xxxxxxx/getFlowersList.php?id=' +widget.itemHolder;`

Comment: Hi bro still I get error (The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.) @Mobina

Comment: I'm not a bro :) Don't make the variable final and initialize it in `initState`.

Comment: Do you mean widget.itemHolder ?

Comment: @Mobina I'm sorry. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 ... 
 String apiURL; 

 @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    apiURL = 'http://xxxxxxx/getFlowersList.php?id=' +widget.itemHolder.toString(); 
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Hi bro : I get error when I use widget like : The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Comment: Shouldn't give you this error, be sure to write the code the same way you wrote the answer

Comment: remove this line from your code : final String apiURL = 'http://xxxxxxxxx/getFlowersList.php';

Comment: see this photo please: https://c.top4top.io/p_1690qsbps1.png

Comment: just add .toString() , like my answer, Sorry, I modified it, I thought you saw it

Comment: The message says you cannot assign a numeric value to a text variable, you must convert it to text first

Comment: It's work now .Thank you, brother. I wish to you all the best

Answer (score 0):

To use the variables declared in the SecondScreen  you have to access it with the prefix 'widget' and the dot operator, not directly. Here is the code:

```
  final String apiURL = 'http://xxxxxxx/getFlowersList.php?id=' + widget.itemHolder;
```

And when you make the variable final, you have to initialize it while declaration or through constructor else delete keyword final:

Comment: Hi bro I get this error :The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Comment: You have still not initialized the item holder

Comment: How I can do it sorry but I'm new in flutter

Comment: Im sorry, you had done it. But i dont see any error, Are you sure you have proper brackets. Because the error says you are in initializer. Also try removing final in the line you get error